# Getting like_info for fb status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the FB api, when I'm fetching data from `/statuses` I get an array of likes that is limited to 25. I'm trying to get the total **like_count**, and am trying to avoid using the pagination in the like array (as it can be many requests with data I don't need). For `photos` and `links` I'm using an FQL query to the `photo` and `link` tables getting the `like_info` var.

However, in the status table there's not such var. Any way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use an FQL request for statuses as well?

```
select message, type, updated_time, likes 
  from stream 
 where source_id=me() 
   and type=46
       LIMIT 100
```

`type` represents the type of the story where 46 is a Status update.

The `likes` field is an array which contains a `count` key. You can use that.

---

**Edit:** OK this first query wasn't really profitable.

I now suggest you to keep querying `graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/statuses` and to count the amount of likes by yourself (will be between 0 and 25).

If you get 25 likes, it means that there might be more likes for the status. For such statuses, you will specifically need to make another single request to get the like count of the post. You'll need:

- a POSTID: the `id` of the post (it looks like `"id": "10200225192185456"`),
- a USERID: the `id` of the user.

By concatenating USERID and POSTID separated by an underscore (`_`), you'll get what we won't call a `POST_ID` anymore but an `OBJECT_ID`. An OBJECT_ID looks like: 1022369831_10200225192185456. You'll have to build the object id by yourself using your own language.

Then, you can use this OBJECT_ID to query the POST table and get more complete information about the status.

```
graph.facebook.com/USERID_POSTID?fields=likes
```

Or:

```
graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID?fields=likes
```

The `likes` field now contains a `count` information.

Comment: Isn't the stream table limited just to the latest posts? The query you gave seems good but returns very few results (/statuses returns more).

Comment: The updated answer worked great - Thanks! BTW - does fb have any decent documentation for such queries?

Comment: Hum not really. What I actually do is to play with the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and see how things work.

Comment: Any way to only query for the count field inside likes? You would say this is ordinary to first bring the object and then re-request such meta-data?